# Bash (Mac) Script: How do I compare two strings?

Tags: bash, macos

so I'm writing a script that compares file names in different directories.  I wrote this:

```
for name in `ls <directory>` 
do  
     for folder in `ls <directory 2>`
     do
          if [[ “$name” == “$folder” ]] 
          then
               echo “These names are the same"
          else
               echo "These names are different"
          fi
     done
done
```

Basically I have a file in one area (ie the desktop) named ABC.  Then I have a folder in another area (ie in Documents) named ABC.  This script should recognize them as the same and display "These names are the same."  If the folder was named XYZ however, it would display "These names are different."

When I tried it on my mac though, the script did not work.  However, when I had someone else write the same script on a linux OS, the script was able to recognize the same/different names.

Is there some syntax thing that I am messing up?  I learned about these commands in a linux context, so it is possible I am doing something wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by "did not work"?

Comment: This seems like a horrible way to compare anything.

Comment: Are you sure that the script is executing on OSX using bash? what does the shebang line look like? Maybe the script is actually executing using `sh` which doesn't support `[[ ]]` for comparison.

Comment: I'm new to scripting.  Is there a better way to compare things in two different directories?  Everything I've tried always fails to recognize the same/different names

Comment: OSX has "smart quotes" turned on by default which replaces double quotes with unicode slanted quotes. Your posted script has several, and bash doesn't understand them. Disable smart quotes, replace the `“` and `”` with regular `"`, then try again and repost the script.

Comment: Yes that worked!  Thanks for not roasting my code like some of the other guys.  Are there better features for string comparison that I could read about to improve what I have given that this seems like a horrible way to compare things?

Comment: If you're just try to find out if one file exists in a folder and another doesn't you can use `diff -r /folder1 /folder2` ... It's unclear what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: I'm running a data analysis program that takes a file of specific formats (you enter the path to the file) and then converts it to a folder containing multiple subfolders, one of which contains the file in a format readable by the program.  However, if the file already exists (already converted) my script gets messed up due to features of that program.  I was trying to write a script that would let me automatically process the data but also check for duplicates so the files already converted would be skipped and the program would not be interrupted.  I hope I explained that well